# Pivoting data to show unique values for specific columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, ssms, distinct

I have a table:

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | G | CA | DA | EA |
| 2 | Y | G | CA | DA | EA |
| 3 | Y | Q | CA | DA | EA |
| 1 | X | G | RA | DA | EA |
| 2 | X | G | CA | DA | EA |
| 3 | X | Q | CA | DA | EA |

For col1 and col2, I want to create 4 additional columns. Two for the distinct values for col1 (X,Y) and two for the distinct values for col2 (G,Q). For example, if the ID 1 have col1 = X then I want to display 'Y' under col1_X. How do I do that? I think I'll need a pivot/group by as I would want to eliminate duplicated rows of data.

Desired output:

| ID | col3 | col4 | col5 | col1_X | col1_Y | col2_G | col2_Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | N |
| 1 | RA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | N |
| 2 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | Y | N |
| 3 | CA | DA | EA | Y | Y | N | Y |

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression for each new column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, col3, col4, col5,
       CASE WHEN col1 = 'X' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END col1_X,
       CASE WHEN col1 = 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END col1_Y,
       CASE WHEN col2 = 'G' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END col2_G,
       CASE WHEN col2 = 'Q' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END col2_Q
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=828d6805f1c6ba6b53795dd29097c678).

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I've updated my original post. I have duplicated lines that I want to eliminate - I think I'll need a pivot/group by

Comment: @BKB no, you just need DISTINCT. Check my edited code and the demo link.

Comment: The case when statements is considered as part of the distinct and because of that I still have duplicated lines. I think my original sample data wasn't great, For each ID I have different col1 and col2. Do you think in this case I need a group by?

Comment: @BKB for this case you don't need a GROUP BY because you are not doing any aggregation. If you want distinct rows you need DISTINCT which guarantees that there are not duplicate rows, so I don't understand what you mean by *I still have duplicated lines*.

Comment: I've updated my data to reflect the use case. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5075e45bd0c1bc6932095f835024dff0     I have now 6 lines instead of 4.

Comment: I want each unique ID, col3, col4, col5 combination to appear as one line and the 4 cases to denote whether these values exists

Comment: @BKB are you finished updating the sample data and your expected results again and again? My answer is about the question as you originally posted it. Your question now has nothing to do with what you originally asked for. If your requirement is different you can post a new question where you explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive solution but may help to get to a more dynamic way of approaching the problem:

```
drop table if exists #test;
drop table if exists #result;

create table #test (
    [ID] int,
    [col1] varchar(1),
    [col2] varchar(1),
    [col3] varchar(2),
    [col4] varchar(2),
    [col5] varchar(2));

insert into #test ([ID], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5]) 
values
(1, 'Y', 'G', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(2, 'Y', 'G', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(3, 'Y', 'Q', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(1, 'X', 'G', 'RA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(2, 'X', 'G', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA'),
(3, 'X', 'Q', 'CA', 'DA', 'EA');

-- create the output table
select 
distinct ID, col3, col4, col5, 
    'N' as col1_X, 'N' as col1_Y, 'N' as col2_G, 'N' as col2_Q
into #result 
from #Test;

-- update the results
update t1
set t1.col1_X = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.col3 = t1.col3 and t2.col4 = t1.col4 and t2.col5 = t1.col5 
    and t2.col1 = 'X');

update t1
set t1.col1_Y = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.col3 = t1.col3 and t2.col4 = t1.col4 and t2.col5 = t1.col5
    and t2.col1 = 'Y');

update t1
set t1.col2_G = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.col3 = t1.col3 and t2.col4 = t1.col4 and t2.col5 = t1.col5
    and t2.col2 = 'G');

update t1
set t1.col2_Q = 'Y'
from #result t1
where exists (select * from #test t2 
    where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.col3 = t1.col3 and t2.col4 = t1.col4 and t2.col5 = t1.col5 
    and t2.col2 = 'Q');


select * from #result;
```